# How to reduce an array of objects inside an array of objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is array reduce the best option for this or any other better options like using lodash

For eg:-
The array that needs to be reduced

```
let A1 = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "agency": "Sel A.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q4"," comment": "Test Data 1"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 2"},
        {"quarter": "Q2", "comment": "Test Data 3"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "agency": "Sel B.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q1", "comment": "Test Data 4"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 5"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 6"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "agency": "Sel C.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q2", "comment": "Test Data 7"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 8"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 9"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "agency": "Sel D.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q1", "comment": "Test Data 10"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": ""},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 12"}]
    }
];
```

The array with which we get the filter

```
let A2 = ['Q3', Q4];
```

How to reduce array like below where it only filter 'Q3' and 'Q4' and also check if comment is not empty.

```
let res = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "agency": "Sel A.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q4"," comment": "Test Data 1"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 2"}],
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "agency": "Sel B.",
    "analysis": [,
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 5"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 6"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "agency": "Sel C.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 8"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 9"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "agency": "Sel D.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 12"}]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part is that the `filter` happens on a inner level

```js
let A1 = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "agency": "Sel A.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q4"," comment": "Test Data 1"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 2"},
        {"quarter": "Q2", "comment": "Test Data 3"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "agency": "Sel B.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q1", "comment": "Test Data 4"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 5"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 6"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "agency": "Sel C.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q2", "comment": "Test Data 7"},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 8"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": "Test Data 9"}]
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "agency": "Sel D.",
    "analysis": [
        {"quarter": "Q1", "comment": "Test Data 10"},
        {"quarter": "Q4", "comment": ""},
        {"quarter": "Q3", "comment": "Test Data 12"}]
    }
];

let A2 = ['Q3','Q4'];


const res = A1.map( x => {
  const {analysis,...rest} = x
  return {
  analysis: analysis.filter(q => A2.includes(q.quarter) && q.comment ),
  ...rest
  }
  });
  
  console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `reduce` nor `lodash`, you can just use `forEach` on **A1** and then use `filter` on **analysis**

```js
let A1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "agency": "Sel A.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": "Test Data 1"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 2"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q2",
        "comment": "Test Data 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "agency": "Sel B.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q1",
        "comment": "Test Data 4"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 5"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": "Test Data 6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "agency": "Sel C.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q2",
        "comment": "Test Data 7"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 8"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": "Test Data 9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "agency": "Sel D.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q1",
        "comment": "Test Data 10"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": ""
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 12"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let A2 = ['Q3', 'Q4'];

A1.forEach(item => item.analysis = item.analysis.filter(analysis =>
  A2.includes(analysis.quarter) && analysis.comment
))

console.log(A1)
```

Comment: nice approach if you don't need the original `A1` anymore

Answer (score 1):

Below implementation is using lodash library

```js
let A1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "agency": "Sel A.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q4",
        " comment": "Test Data 1"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 2"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q2",
        "comment": "Test Data 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "agency": "Sel B.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q1",
        "comment": "Test Data 4"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 5"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": "Test Data 6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "agency": "Sel C.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q2",
        "comment": "Test Data 7"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 8"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": "Test Data 9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "agency": "Sel D.",
    "analysis": [{
        "quarter": "Q1",
        "comment": "Test Data 10"
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q4",
        "comment": ""
      },
      {
        "quarter": "Q3",
        "comment": "Test Data 12"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let A2 = ['Q3', 'Q4'];

var result = _.map(A1, x => {
  x.analysis = _.filter(x.analysis, analysisChild => A2.includes(analysisChild.quarter));
  return x;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha256-qXBd/EfAdjOA2FGrGAG+b3YBn2tn5A6bhz+LSgYD96k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```